# Labeled data messes up ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I am having problems with the new labeling functions `Labeled` when used in `ListPlot` or any of its sibblings. `Labeled` data can only be shown with the full range. If I apply a partial `PlotRange` the plots is messed up:

```
data = Table[{i, Sin@i}, {i, -50, 50}];

ListLinePlot[Labeled[data, "data"], PlotTheme -> "Frame"]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[Labeled[data, "data"], PlotRange -> {{20, 50}, All},  PlotTheme -> "Frame"]
```

[image]

`Show` doesn't help, as it sometimes does in similar cases. It just adds to the mess:

```
Show[ListLinePlot[Labeled[data, "data"]], PlotRange -> {{20, 50}, All}]
```

[image]

Consistently, the behavior is the same when using `Callout` instead:

[image]

Of course I copuld pre-filter my data, but the whole point of `PlotRange` is not having to do it. I assume this is a bug. Does anybody know of an easy workaround?

**Edit:**

This is on Windows 10, Version 11.2

Comment: `ListLinePlot[Labeled[data, "data", After] ,PlotRange -> {{20, 50}, All}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Frame",   ImagePadding->{{Automatic,30}, {Automatic,Automatic }}]`?

Comment: I find it hard not to consider this a bug.  Please report to determine if it is the intended behavior. (You can use the give feedback button at the bottom of [the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html?q=ListPlot).

Comment: You should specify the M version, and possibly the OS. On OSX, M11.1 exhibits your issue, while M11.2 does not.

Comment: Btw, perhaps `Legended` will meet your immediate need. (Works on 11.1.)

Comment: @kglr This is not an improvement. ImagePadding cuts off all the Labels and Ticks. It would be easier to just omit the Labeled.

Comment: @Alan Yes. I can use PlotLegends, but my example is pretty simplified. The real case is much more crowded and confusing the line colors becomes a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with restricting the plot range, while having labels that exist outside of the plot range is that the option [`PlotRangeClipping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangeClipping) is not smart enough to clip only the data and not the labels. As a workaround, one can use the [`Mesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh) options of [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot) to hide the portion of the plot that shouldn't be seen. This way we don't need to use `PlotRangeClipping->True` to restrict the plot. Here's an example:

```
ListLinePlot[
    {Labeled[data, "data"]},
    PlotTheme -> "Frame",
    PlotRange -> {{20, 50}, All},
    Mesh -> {{{20}, {50}}, {}},
    MeshShading -> {None, Opacity[1]}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. That works. Tank you!

Answer (score 2):

My experience with Mathematica tells me to solve the problem by trimming the data before plotting it, rather than plotting all the data but then restricting the viewport. One way to do it is

```
data = Table[{i, Sin @ i}, {i, -50, 50}];
ListLinePlot[Labeled[Select[data, 20 <= First[#] <= 50 &], "data"], PlotTheme -> "Frame"]
```

But it might even be easier to just generate a new data set.

```
trimedData = Table[{i, Sin @ i}, {i, 20, 50}];
ListLinePlot[Labeled[trimedData, "data"], PlotTheme -> "Frame"]
```

Both plots are same.

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I am aware that pre-filtering is a solution. The point is that I don't want to if I can avoid it. But of course I will do it if no other way shows up.